# Show that if E is compact, then $m(E)= \lim m(O_n)$ (Is my proof correct?)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Hello I was wondering if my proof for the following problem is correct and how to show one of the $O_n$ has finite measure?

Suppose E is a given set, and $O_n$ is the open set
$O_n = \{x: \inf_y |x-y|<\frac{1}{n}\}$
where the infimum is taken over all y in E.
(a) Show that if E is compact, then $ lim(O_n)= m(E) $

my proof) First, I show that $O_n$ tends to E. Clearly, E is in the intersection of $O_n$ so all that is left to show is $O_n$ is in E. Let x belong to the intersection of $O_n$, then there exists a $y_n$ in $O_n$ such that $|x-y_n|<\frac{1}{n} $. This defines a sequence $y_n$ in E which converges to x, and since E is closed, x is in E. Hence E= intersection $O_n$.

Now if I am able to show that one of the $O_n$ has finite measure, then I could use continuity of measure to conclude that $m(O_n)\to m(E)$

How can I do that and is my proof otherwise correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d$?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that $O_n$ is bounded for all $n$? $E$ is compact, hence bounded. Say $E \subset B(0,R)$, then by the triangle inequality $O_n \subset B(0,R+1/n)$.

Comment: Hi, sorry yes E is in R. And even though it was obvious since E is bounded I was not able to show it mathematically...thanks! Otherwise is my proof correct?